# Slow SSD Read on Server 2008 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssd, performance

Im using a Intel X25-M 80G with the latest firmware. on XP /w using IDE and WIN7 using AHCI I get read speeds up to 250MB/S. But when running it with Server 2008 SP1 or SP2 on AHCI, I get read speeds around 180MB/S. Ive updated drivers for 2008, tested with writecache on/off.

Any input would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the disk caching options to see if they are different between server and client OSes

Comment: Is anyone else amused by the notion that 180MB/s is "slow"?

Answer (score 3):

The only operating system that shares an identical file system with server 2008 is Vista... If your results are similar on Vista then it is indicative of limitations with this file system.  Server 2008/Vista were the first generation to receive self-healing NTFS but lacked TRIM and proper SSD optimizations which Windows 7 has.  As for why XP is faster.. perhaps it lacks the feature which is causing the slowdown in 2008 that was remedied in windows 7.

To test this theory you would have to try the drive in AHCI mode on Vista.